# Linux fstab cifs NAS mount shows empty folder

Tags: linux, mount, nas, fstab, cifs

I am trying to mount my Nas in my home directory. This is also no problem at first, but when I restart my laptop Linux mounts it as a network, but the folder is empty. It also only shows the available storage on my hard drive and not how mutch is available on the NAS. Here is my fstab:

```
//192.168.0.100/Philipp /home/philipp/Cloud cifs 
rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,username=philipp,password=xxxxxxx
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually mounted? How did you check?

Comment: It shows up as network in my file browser and there I can press unmount and it throws an error. In the console it says that it is not even mountet. Do you know why?